# How to RSA sign using only modulus and private key exponent (d)?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to preform private key operation like RSA sign using **only** (n) and (d).
My system exposes an API which only (n) and (d) inputs, sadly I can't change the API itself.

Since I'm using the latest OpenSSL release I have to use the setter: `RSA_set0_key` which mandates providing the (n) and (e), regardless to the operation that will be made using the given RSA (private key operation in my case)

**So my questions is:**

Can I perform RSA signing operation using only (n) and (d)?
I don't want to guess the public exponent and I can't receive it in the process.

If the answer is NO.
Can I use arbitrary prime number as (e) for the `RSA_set0_key`? does the EVP/rsa_sign functions will validate that the public exponent is compatible with the private?

Thanks

Comment: Mathematically yes, but I don't know if it's possible with OpenSSL.

Comment: What good is a private key if you don't have the public key?

Comment: I'm exposing an API which accepts only the (n) and (d), and can't change the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, if you only know one exponent (d or e) and the modulus (n), you can't easily find the inverse exponent (e or d) without knowing the factors of the modulus -- that's why RSA is secure.

However, most RSA implementations use a fixed exponent for e -- generally 65537 (0x10001), so you really only need to know n.

Now your question is a bit strange, as RSA signing only uses N and D -- you need E to verify the signature.  `RSA_get0_key` *gives* you N and D and E from an RSA key object.  Perhaps you mean `RSA_set0_key` which is for putting values into a RSA key object?  That only requires that you provide N, though if you leave E unset you won't be able to verify signatures or encrypt data.  As long as you set D (and N), you should be able to generate signatures just fine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you haven't answered the question.

Comment: I did meant RSA_set0_key, and this function cant set only N and d, this is my problem

Comment: Also please note that e can be some other prime, and not 65537.
Guessing the e could be a w/a that I think should be the last resort.

Comment: You can guess *and test*. If you have `N` and `e` then you can use the public key to verify any signature you put over data. I'd start with the fourth prime of Fermat and then test from 3 up to 65536 if that doesn't work. The chance that a large value is used is abysmally small, a lot of API's won't even allow it.

Comment: This will me the last resort, for my it's a very bad solution.
I don't understand why I need to supply e for private key operation....

Comment: @KernelingTheCompiler: the only argument to RSA_set0_key that can't be null is n -- either of the other two may be null.

Comment: Chris, you are wrong. "The values n and e must be non-NULL the first time this function is called on a given RSA object." Ref: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_set0_key.html

Comment: Interesting -- I'm not sure why they changed that in recent versions.  I guess you can't use set0_key and have to manually set the fields of the RSA object if you want to set just n and d and not e.

Comment: You can't manually set the fields any more....
I can't understand why they changed this?